# Php Code (Get/Fetch Kongregate Games)

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Can you help me there is a problem that is detect by php when execute but I think my code is okay.

The error say "Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\getkongregate.php on line 46"

Website of kongregate xml: [here](http://www.kongregate.com/games_for_your_site.xml)

This is the code I have:

```
    <?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('http://www.kongregate.com/games_for_your_site.xml'));
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        $games = json_decode($json);
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($games->game as $game) {
            echo $game->id . "\n";
            echo $game->title . "\n";
            echo $game->thumbnail . "\n";
            echo $game->launch_date . "\n";
            echo $game->category . "\n";
            if (array_key_exists('screenshot',$game)) {
                for($i=0;$i<=(count($game->screenshot)-1);$i++) {
                    echo $game->screenshot[$i] . "\n";
                }
            }
            echo $game->flash_file . "\n";
            echo $game->width . "\n";
            echo $game->height . "\n";
            echo $game->description . "\n";
            echo $game->instructions . "\n";
            echo $game->gameplays . "\n";
            echo $game->rating . "\n\n------\n\n";
        if ($count == 100) {break;}
        $count++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are retreiving xml.

Why are you parsing it as json?

Use SimpleXmlElement instead and then iterate through xml elements to retreive your data.

```
$xml = file_get_contents($map_url);
$simpleXmlElement = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($simpleXmlElement);
```

Here: :)

```
$url = 'http://www.kongregate.com/games_for_your_site.xml';
$content = file_get_contents($url)
$xml = simplexml_load_string($content);

$count = 0;
foreach ($xml as $game) {

    echo strval($game->id) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->title) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->thumbnail) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->launch_date) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->category) . PHP_EOL;

    if (isset($game->screenshot) && is_array($game->screenshot)) {
        foreach ($game->screenshot as $screenshot) {
            echo strval($screenshot) . "\n";
        }
    }

    echo strval($game->flash_file) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->width) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->height) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->description) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->instructions) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->gameplays) . PHP_EOL;
    echo strval($game->rating) . PHP_EOL;

    if ($count >= 100) {
        break;
    }
    $count++;
}
```